# Default font "UbuntuRegular" has bad rendering on umlaut characters

Tags: bug, style, font

The default font "UbuntuRegular" used by Ask Ubuntu is messed up on umlaut characters. Affected characters seem smaller than normal. I played around the font-size and it doesn't help with the problem.

This seems to happen with all umlaut characters like ÄäÖöÅåÜüÑñ and so on.

```
# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

**UbuntuRegular on Ask Ubuntu**

[image: Me]

**Arial on Stack Overflow**

[image]

Given that there are not too many posts with umlauts on AU this still looks very weird in running text, see the example.

[image]

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: @muru I use Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with how Stack Exchange calls the font family. I edited the element's CSS to test:

- Named `Ubuntu`:
  [image]
- Named `Ubuntu Regular`
  [image]
- Named `UbuntuRegular` (no space)
  [image]
  Note how the lack of fall-back families causes these characters to be shown in Serif font.

(I'm on Windows, and also have the Ubuntu font installed.)

I'd say the family should be set to `'Ubuntu Regular', Ubuntu, 'Bitstream ...` instead of the current `UbuntuRegular, Ubuntu, 'Bitstream Vera Sans...` .

Comment: It should be `Ubuntu, UbuntuRegular, 'Bitstream ...` Where the Ubuntu font on users machines takes precedence

Comment: @MarcoCeppi you sure? Ubuntu is more generic than Ubuntu regular, so specifying it first would mean Ubuntu regular will never be matched.

Comment: Yes, because if the user does not have Ubuntu the font installed it should move on to UbuntuRegular which is loaded with Google Fonts and will almost always match

Comment: @MarcoCeppi that depends on how specific the call to Google web fonts is. I use it on my site and it loads the generic Ubuntu family as well.

Comment: Well, considering it's defined in the CSS as UbuntuRegular and no actual font exists on the users machine as UbuntuRegular it will always match the webfont.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi any course of action to improve the situation?

Answer (score 0):

This should be reported as a bug to the UbuntuFont project, it's nothing Stack Exchange controls

Comment: You control the fonts displayed on this site. eg. font "Ubuntu" works just fine.

Comment: Ubuntu.com uses "Ubuntu" font instead of "UbuntuRegular", why doesn't askubuntu.com do the same?

Comment: StackExchange seems to have control over the fonts as StackOverflow uses different fonts than AskUbuntu.

Comment: UbuntuRegular is the Ubuntu font. Ubuntu is the family, Regular is the weight. UbuntuRegular is a Google fonts naming scheme used to load the Ubuntu font for users who don't have it installed.